# Ubuntu guest can't connect to the internet

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualbox, dns

I'm having an Ubuntu guest on a Win10 host. Until recently everything was fine and working, but then I've upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and my internet connection is now gone, for some unknown reason. No Win10 configuration was changed.

I use bridged adapter (as before), and while our local network servers are available (i.e I push/pull to the remote git server with no problem), outside world is unreachable.

It might be related (or not), but it seems that part of my root privileges have been revoked, as many more commands won't run now unless I add `sudo` before.

I've seen those solutions editing `/etc/resolv.conf`, this didn't work out at all. Also tried some `netplan` stuff (as explained [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/)), also didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: *part of my root privileges have been revoked, as many more commands won't run now unless I add sudo before* - that is very unusual indeed. I suspect that permissions of your HOME in the guest Ubuntu do not match your user. Do the programs work in the guest account?

Comment: it's things like accessing the `/media` folder and making changes, I wouldn't expect guest user to have these privileges. Anyway the internet access thing is painful, any thoughts?